# How well known is S.H.I.E.L.D.?

Tags: marvel-cinematic-universe, marvel, agents-of-shield

How much of the world knows about S.H.I.E.L.D.? I thought it was well known throughout the world but in the first episode of the third season of Agents of S.H.I.E.L.D. when

> Daisy tells Joey Gutierrez that they are S.H.I.E.L.D. and he asks who are they, implying that he doesn't know about them. But near the end of the episode the President talks about S.H.I.E.L.D. and its failures.

Did I miss something or was

> Joey just out of the loop?

Comment: Given that President Ellis is talking about them in a press conference, and referencing SHIELD's involvement in the DC/Triskellion attack, the world seems to already know a fair bit. Joey seems to either be out of the loop, or just shocked/confused by everything going on.

Comment: It might also be that the general public, Joey included, believe SHIELD to be extinct now and that if someone is using the name it has to be a different group.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**SHIELD were a publicly known and legal organisation. That is no longer the case.**

SHIELD was disbanded and shut down after the events of *Captain America: The Winter Soldier*, which revealed to us that Hydra had been growing within SHIELD for many decades. Since then, the version of SHIELD that we see in show has been classified as a rogue organisation, mostly due the fact that Hydra attacked the United Nations in season two of *Agents of SHIELD* while pretending to be SHIELD.

Thie situation is explained in dialouge in "Laws of Nature", the first episode of season three of *Agents of SHIELD*. At one point, the leader of the ATCU, Rosalind Price, and the Director of SHIELD, Phil Coulson, discuss the secrets that they know about each other, causing Rosalind to reveal that she knows all about Colsoun's death and revival through the TAHITI program. Her exact line is;

> **In the eyes of the public, SHIELD no longer exists**. And you were killed long before the agency you work for was pronounced dead.

<sup><sup>Rosalind Price, *Agents of SHIELD* episode "Laws of Nature"</sup></sup>

This would seem to confirm that despite the on-going SHIELD activity that we have seen in *Agents of SHIELD*, the general population are not aware that SHIELD continue to operate, at least legally.

Comment: @Howli No problem, thanks very much.